# R doesn't recognize quotation mark when copied from somewhere else and font was Courier new

Tags: r, ascii, quotation-marks

I have a problem where I create some R code snippets in other tools. In my case I create some code snippets in ppt with font set to Courier New.

However, when I want to paste that code into R (more precise Rstudio), R doesn't recognize the quotation marks correctly.

E.g. a text snippet like `test <- "test"` won't be recognized correctly in R(Studio).

I guess this might be related to the "left" and "right" versions of Courier News quotation marks.

What I'm unsure is who's to blame? The font? The input tool (Powerpoint) or the output tool (R)?

And regardless of the above: any ideas how to solve this? (except "change the font from Courier New to sth. else")

See below a screenshot of how the above code snippet looks in ppt with font Courier New:

[image]

Comment: MS Office products have the option of replacing straight quotes with "smart" quotes.  They are a different character.   Search the PowerPoint options for "Smart quotes" and you can turn it off.   For example in PPT 16 for Mac it is under Preferences > AutoCorrect> AutoFormat as you type.

Comment: That's it. Thanks. Altough I would either expect powerpoint to copy them as their original characters or R to be able to recognize these typographic quotation marks. I mean they probably have their own ascii code and R should detect tehse as valid quotes, no?

Comment: @deschen No, ASCII does not contain codes for these left and right double quotation marks. I don't know of any language that accepts these characters in place of regular double quotes. To copy them as their original characters would require your document to keep track of the fact that it converted them for you, rather than you actually entering it like that. Do you also feel that Powerpoint should keep track of every misspelled word that its spellcheck feature has fixed for you, in case you want to copy-paste it elsewhere with original mistakes intact?

Comment: Well, slack for example dose change them back to their original format. OK, slack is not a coding language per se, but it does the conversion correctly, so it's definitely technical possible. Regarding keeping track...well, to be honest, if a software automatically changes something, it should be locked IMO, but I do see that it probably would be inconsistent to automatically revert to an original state for copy pasting quotation marks but not for e.g. typos (or vice versa).

Comment: It is not a *technical* matter. The "smart quotes" are Office trying to be helpful for a common workflow; it is a UI/UX matter. But c&p from non-ASCII characters into RStudio isn't a common workflow, so not surprising that it doesn't try to convert them (AFAICT, Slack doesn't either?). If you're suggesting the R interpreter should just deal with it, it raises questions about how matching string delimiters should work and is just a source of further errors (e.g. a string between two left double quotes, or a regular double quote and a right, and they happen to look very similar in a font, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Curious this one. I think that your problems have to two possible sources: 1) comes from the encoding of your powerpoint. RStudio uses a lot of UTF-8 (encoding system) around him, so maybe the quotation marks are coming wrong, because of different encoding. 2) possible some cusomization that powerpoint applies in your text, like puting quotation marks facing each others, as would appear normally in text's and articles. So, if you want to create code, you should do it in specialized tools (e.g. Notepad++), or in a plain note document.